# Why is light being reflected off of one side?

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, eevee-render-engine, lighting, reflection

I'm trying to set up a scene with lighting. But, for some reason, the lights seem to be reflecting off of one side. It does this for both eevee renders and cycles renders. Does anyone know how to fix this?[image]

Comment: Flipped normals, maybe? It's kinda hard to tell from the photo.

Comment: what should the light do? (also flipped normals is probably not it)

Comment: I tried flipping normals, but it still doesn't work. I'm trying to get the light to reflect off of both walls. Not just one.